# Better alternative for encapsulation and information hiding

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `Framework` that the user can implement by overriding some member functions accepting a reference to an `Object`. The user is not allowed to call `Object::do_something()` from any of those functions except `Framework::f()`. To implement this requirement I had to introduce an `Helper` class with a static member function, as in the following example. I wonder if there is something shorter or cleaner.

```
class Object;

struct Framework { // the interface is fixed
protected:
    virtual void f(Object& o); // f is allowed to call o.do_something()
    virtual void g(Object& o); // g is not allowed to call o.do_something()
    friend class Helper;
};

class Helper { // Helper class to make things work as wanted
    friend class Object;
    friend void Framework::f(Object&);
    static void helper(Object&);
};

class Object {
    void do_something() {}
    friend void Helper::helper(Object&);
  public:
    void do_something_else() {}  
};

void Helper::helper(Object& o) {o.do_something();}

// user implementation
void Framework::f(Object& o) {Helper::helper(o);}
void Framework::g(Object& o) {o.do_something_else(); /*Helper::helper(o);*/} // o.do_something() denied
```

Comment: Why not to pass Object to only those functions that are allowed to use it (like `f`) and do not pass to others (`g`)?

Comment: because g is allowed to call other member functions of Object

Comment: This is not clean from your question. I think it's better to state it explicitly.

Comment: @maverik i added another public member function to Object

Comment: You state that the interface of `Framework` is fixed. How fixed is the interface of `Object`? Can you refactor that? Because `do_something()` is private, so how can `f()` call it?

Comment: The `friend` statement inside `Helper` lets `Object` acces it, but not the other way around, are you sure that's how it is in your code?

Comment: @TemplateRex yes, my code was like I wrote. However, I ended up with refactoring the whole cde as you suggested in your answer, by making Object abstract. It seems there are no ther alternatives, although i have would liked to have Object non abstract for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should declare `void f(Object& o)` as a `friend` for the `Object` class as you did for the `void Helper::helper(Object&)` method.